# help with linq query

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework

i have table

> id  pagenane username

i want this sql query

> select pagename, count(*) as num from pagestat where username='name' group by pagename

how can i do it by linq?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, try this:

```
var query = from row in context.pageStat
            where row.UserName == "name"
            group row by row.PageName into g
            select new { PageName = g.Key, Count = g.Count() };
```

Comment: how can i return this value from function? something like return query.ToList(); but this is anonymous type

Comment: @kusanagi: If you're using .NET 4 you could use tuples; otherwise you could just create your own named type with the pagename and count as properties... basically a named version of the anonymous type.

Comment: Note that `row.UserName == "name"` will be case-sensitive. Perhaps not what you want for a username, and (depending on the DB collation) perhaps not what the original SQL query did. Use `row.UserName.Equals("name", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)` for an insensitive comparison; it's supported in both L2S and L2E.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var retVal = (from s in dataContext.YourTable where

s.UserName.Equals("name")
group s by s.PageName into k
select new {PageName = k.Key, Count = k.Count() }).ToList();
```

Comment: `s` won't be in scope in the `select` clause. At that point you're dealing with *groups* rather than an individual record. Fortunately you can use the key of the group.

Comment: Thank you Jon, I will be careful, fixing now.